# How to refresh a div tag after an AJAX call using jQuery in a Spring boot application?

Tags: jquery, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to refresh a `div` tag after an AJAX call in a Spring boot app using jQuery. I used the `load()` method of jQuery but it will call mapping method of the controller layer. I want to refresh it without calling the controller. Is this possible?

```html
<div id="instructor-block-wrapper" class="row inner_sec_info pt-md-4">
  <div id="details-details-block" class="col-lg-8 single-left">
    <ul>
      <li style="font-size: 120%" class="mt-3">
        <a href="">First Name</a><i style="color: red;"> : </i>
        <a th:text="${session.instructorToDisplay.firstName}"></a>
      </li>
      <li style="font-size: 120%" class="mt-3">
        <i class="fas fa-check mr-2"></i>
        <a href="">Last Name</a><i style="color: red;"> : </i>
        <a th:text="${session.instructorToDisplay.lastName}"></a>
      </li>
      <li style="font-size: 120%" class="mt-3 ">
        <i class="fas fa-check mr-2"></i>
        <a href="">Register No</a><i style="color: red;"> : </i>
        <a th:text="${session.instructorToDisplay.registerationNumber}"></a>
      </li>
      <li style="font-size: 120%" class="mt-3">
        <i class="fas fa-check mr-2"></i>
        <a href="">Degree</a><i style="color: red;"> : </i>
        <a th:text="${session.instructorToDisplay.degree}"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#searchInsructorButton', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var registerNo = $("#search-instructor-pattern").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/instructor/search-instructor?regno=" + registerNo,
    success: function(result) {
      if (result.status) {
        $("#instructor-block-wrapper").load(location.href + ' #instructor-block-wrapper')
      } else {
        $("#search-wrong-msg-instructor").text("Instructor not exist");
        return;
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error! please enter proper data");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Where would you refresh it from without using the controller?

Comment: when I search for an item using ajax call i reinitialized the session instructorToDisplay value with new object but after ajax call it will still show the previous item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following in you response

```
$('#showresults').html($('#showresults',data).html());
```

or

```
$('#showresults').replaceWith($('#showresults',data));
```

Comment: Zahid Rahman  thanks from your answer .but what is data here.I mean I save the data in session and from session i will display it.

Comment: Data is representing your data if you need to update any ?

Comment: But here i am displaying data from session.and after searching an item i reinitialize session data. can you look at the code once

Answer (score -1):

In response try add:

```
$("#yourdivid").load(" #yourdivid");
```

P.S. Leve that space in there `" #yourdivid"`